# TreeCell don't update it's font color

Tags: java, javafx

I have an `TreeView` with multiple `TreeItem<Object>`. My goal is to change the font color of an `TreeCell` on double-click. When another `TreeCell` ist double-clicked on then the color jumps to that new `TreeCell` and restores the default color from the previous. My problem is that the color changes but the previous doesn't restore. The color only changes back when I select the previous one. Here is my MWE:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeViewTest extends Application {

    private TreeCell<TreeData> previous;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TreeView<TreeData> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        treeView.setEditable(true);

        TreeItem<TreeData> root = new TreeItem<>(new TreeData("root", "root"));
        root.setExpanded(true);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            TreeItem<TreeData> level1 = new TreeItem<>(new TreeData("Number " + i, "level"));
            level1.setExpanded(true);
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
                level1.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new TreeData("Subnumber " + i + "." + j, "child")));
            root.getChildren().add(level1);
        }
        treeView.setRoot(root);

        treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> {
            TreeCellImpl treeCell = new TreeCellImpl();

            treeCell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
                TreeData cellItem = ((TreeCellImpl) e.getSource()).getItem();
                // disable double click expand/collapse
                if (e.getClickCount() % 2 == 0 && e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (cellItem.type.equals("root") || cellItem.type.equals("level"))
                        e.consume();
                }
                // on one double click
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                        && cellItem.type.equals("level")) {
                    // go into edit mode
                    treeView.edit(((TreeCellImpl) e.getSource()).getTreeItem());
                }
            });

            return treeCell;
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(treeView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private final class TreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<TreeData> {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(TreeData item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
                setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                if (getItem().type.equals("level") && getItem().flag)
                    setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            }
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            System.out.println("EDIT");
            if (getItem().type.equals("level")) {
                if (previous != null)
                    previous.cancelEdit();
                previous = this;
                getItem().flag = true;
                commitEdit(getItem());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            System.out.println("CANCEL");
            if (getItem().type.equals("level")) {
                getItem().flag = false;
                commitEdit(getItem());
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class TreeData {
        String text;
        String type;
        boolean flag;

        public TreeData(String text, String type) {
            this.text = text;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me what I'm missing or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: tplease explain what you are _really_ after :) Doesn't appear to be double-click, but either editing or related to a property of your item (flag)?. There are some quirks with your code, f.i. a) changing a data property under the feet of the tree editing mechanism b) calling commit in startEdit and cancelEdit c) having a reference to another cell and changing its state ...

Comment: The `addEventFilter` was added to avoid collapsing when double-clicking on the `TreeItem` "level". Then I go into edit mode to play a video. The change of text color just highlights that the video of this `TreeItem` is currently playing. The color should just hightlight which video of the tree is currently playing. This is indicated with the `flag` boolean, in this example.

Comment: to answer your question: yes, you are doing it fundamentally wrong, in particular the reference to another cell and modifying any state of that cell :) Why do you need edit mode when playing a video? Both are unrelated ..

Comment: Okay, you got a point. I was too focused on that edit mode thingy. But I still need TreeCell to color the font. So it's better just to start playing the video on the mouse pressed event and color the cell with `((TreeCellImpl) e.getSource()).setTextFill(Color.GREEN)`?

Comment: not really - you need to detangle your logic/data (only a single video playing, I assume?) from the view. Make that state observable, fire the appropriate treeModificationEvent when it changes, toggle it on whatever event and the view (== cell that is aware of the state) will follow.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you start editing a new `TreeCell`, you can change the color of the previous one after cancelling its edit :

```
@Override
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();
    System.out.println("EDIT");
    if(getItem().type.equals("level"))
    {
        if(previous!=null) // Check if previous exists
        {
            previous.cancelEdit(); //Cancel edit
            previous.setTextFill(Color.BLACK); // Reset color
        }
        previous=this;
        getItem().flag=true;
        commitEdit(getItem());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. But why I have to set the fill color in edit mode? I thought that commiting an edit triggers the updateItem method?

Comment: don't replicate the errors of the question! sibling cells are strictly off limits ..